# How to add a new EC2 instance (from account A) to a ECS cluster (account B) in AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

So I have 2 aws accounts,

- in one I have the ECS Cluster
- in the other one I have a few EC2 instances

How to tell those EC2 instances to connect to that ECS cluster?

I was reading here [How to register EC2 Instance to ECS cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462657/how-to-register-ec2-instance-to-ecs-cluster) that you could lunch an instance and edit the /etc/ecs/ecs.config but there is only `CS_CLUSTER={cluster_name}` to change, not sure how to reference a cluster from the other account/region.

Comment: in that case you can do vpc peering. may i will work

Comment: Thanks but the cluster and instances are on different regions. Any solution cross region?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-multiple-region-multi-vpc-connectivity/ check this out ........https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmCEFGDTb8U

Comment: What do you mean by "connect to that ECS cluster"? Do you want the EC2 instances to connect to a web server running on containers in ECS? Or do you want the EC2 instances to host containers for that cluster? Would you might if I also ask _why?_

Comment: I want my EC2 from account A to register in the cluster of account B, so yes, I need the cluster from account B to deploy new version when the service/task is updated in aws. That's how is setup for now and can't be changed.

Comment: Question... why do you want to do this?