# Why doesn't my EC2 instance register with the ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am creating an AWS ECS cluster (Networking + Linux).

I follow all the steps, set up the subnets and use the existing VPC and the EC2 instance is created.

However, when I go into my cluster > ECS Instances I don't see any EC2 instances there. It doesn't seem to register there.

My EC2 instance has a public IP so that should not be an issue. What could be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to register EC2 Instance to ECS cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462657/how-to-register-ec2-instance-to-ecs-cluster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified in the question, but  normally you also should modify your [UserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) so that it registers with the [non-default cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=<your-cluster-name> >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

Also `Amazon ECS-optimized AMI` should be used which has pre-installed ECS Agent.

Edit: Also need to make sure that instances have **access to the ECS Service**, for example by having public IP and internet access. Without that, ECS Agent won't be able to communicate with the ECS Service.

UserData in console can be specified in the following configuration:

[image]

You can also use [Launch Templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchTemplates.html) or [Launch Configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchConfiguration.html) to specify the UserData reduce the amount of work needed when launching new instances.

Comment: Actually what I also tried and it worked is that I set up that EC2 instance with a public IP address and a security group that allows incoming connections over port 80. And finally it registered. Do you know why this happens like that?

Comment: @Aerodynamika Public IP is needed so that the ECS Agent can communicate with ECS service. Port 80 may be relevant to your application. I will update the answer with the IP, if you don't mind.

Comment: Please, do, because it seems like this is another way. Could you please also specify in a bit more detail how to modify `UserData`? Is this a file and where is it found? Thanks!

Comment: @Aerodynamika Sure, how do you lunch the instances, using Console, or CloudFormation, CLI? I can provide UserData info specific to your use-case.

Comment: Using the Console, the AWS' UI