# How to link a ECS Cluster with an ECS instance in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have created a task definition, an ECS Service and an ECS Cluster but I'm facing trouble registering an ECS Instance in Terraform with the ECS Cluster.How to link an ECS Cluster with an ECS Instance using Terraform?

Comment: What do you mean when you say an ECS Instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an ECS Capacity Provider it would manage this for you.

If you are creating the EC2 instances yourself, you need to provide the cluster ID to the ECS agent running on the instance. When the ECS agent stars up it will then register itself with the cluster. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37218766/13070) for the details of configuring the ECS agent on instance launch.

Comment: Could you provide me an example on how to associate a ECS cluster with a capacity provider?

Comment: In the ECS web console, when viewing your ECS cluster, there is a capacity provider tab.