# When I Want To Run Task To AWS ECS cluster With Launch Type EC2 Warning Appeard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhlxJ.png)

I Have EC2 INstance With IAM Role Which Has Following Permissions:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqLws.png)

Which Is ECS OPTIMIZET

I Want To Containerize My Backend Nest Js Applicaiton With Docker And Push To ECS Cluster But When Creating Task I Got Warning

Comment: Your EC2 instance may have the correct IAM role, but have you configured it to register with your ECS cluster?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462657/how-to-register-ec2-instance-to-ecs-cluster

Answer (score 0):

The warning message indicates your EC2 instance has not registered to the ECS cluster yet.

If the instance registered to the ECS cluster successfully, you should be able to find the instance under "Container instances" section.

[image]

To identify why your instance didn't register to the ECS cluster, please confirm you passed the correct userdata. This was described in this [post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

Please note, the `your_cluster_name` must be changed accordingly.

Also, your IAM Role seems be too permissive. You should be able to use IAM Role `ecsInstanceRole` directly.